# System UI freeze

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, freeze, mouse-pointer

I've installed Ubuntu on a HDD a day ago.
I have the problem, that if I have more than one window open, the system UI does not respond anymore.
I still can switch between the windows with Ctrl Tab (and also work in the windows - like writing in console/Editor) but I can't resize/move/min/max/close the windows. I neither can start another application or access the toolbar.
If I close all windows with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>, the UI works again. (It also works, if I have open one window only).
I could reproduce this problem on Kali (but not on Debian Jessie).

Probably it's a hardware issue?

- CPU: r7 1700
- GPU: r9 290
- RAM: 16GB DDR4 TridentZ RGB 3000MHz @ 2400 (at moment)
- MB: X370-Prime-Pro

I never had this problem before (when I used Linux in an VM on a windows machine).
I just wanted to use Linux natively and now I have this damn problem.

Any ideas on how to fix it?

**EDIT**:
I run `df -h` and thats the result:

```
~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7,8G     0  7,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G  9,9M  1,6G   1% /run
/dev/sdb2       110G  6,9G   98G   7% /
tmpfs           7,9G   12K  7,9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G     0  7,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1,6G  144K  1,6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

**EDIT 2**:

When I login as guest, I don't have that problem.
Today I installed another distribution (elementary os) and I have exactly the same problem. But not when I login as guest.

**EDIT 3**:

It seems to be a focus problem.
When I get multiple windows running and click on the taskbar (when it accepts the input - which is not often) i can move the windows. BUT if I drag a window from the background, it won't switch to foreground. Every window stays in it's z-axis (also the X, square and minus are not highlighted than).

I'd run `df -h` again on both (my user and guest) and get different results now:

My User:

```
~$ df -h
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev            7,8G       0  7,8G    0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G     11M  1,6G    1% /run
/dev/sdb2       110G    6,8G   98G    7% /
tmpfs           7,9G     16K  7,9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G       0  7,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            7,9G     27M  7,9G    1% /tmp/guest-odivyc
tmpfs           1,6G    164K  1,6G    1% /run/user/999
tmpfs           1,6G    128K  1,6G    1% /run/user/1000
```

Guest:

```
~$ df -h
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev            7,8G       0  7,8G    0% /dev
tmpfs           1,6G    9,9M  1,6G    1% /run
/dev/sdb2       110G    6,8G   98G    7% /
tmpfs           7,9G     12K  7,9G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7,9G       0  7,9G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            7,9G     27M  7,9G    1% /tmp/guest-odivyc
tmpfs           1,6G    168K  1,6G    1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdc1       7,5G    1,3G  6,3G   17% /media/guest-odivyc/ELEMENTARY
```

**EDIT 4:**

[I made a quick handy video about the problem](https://youtu.be/PrKyPa_vepc)

Comment: run `df -h` and paste the result here...

Comment: @george I edited my Post.

Comment: Does running the `df -h` command as guest give different results...?

Comment: Then this is strange and really beyond my experience...

Comment: @George, run df -h again, and now it shows some bytes different a a completely other path at bottom?

Comment: Do you have an external storage device attached?

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue. In the VM there is no need of drivers, the drivers of the host OS are used...

Comment: @George only an USB Stick but I didn't remove him since some days (so it should be visible for guest and for user right?)

Comment: @mook765 propably the ryzen CPU?

Comment: Excuse me is this a VM?

Comment: Nope this is Ubuntu on a 120GB partition of one HDD... Windows is on another SSD

Comment: @George `I never had this problem before (when I used Linux in an VM on a windows machine). ` GPU is` Radeon r9 290`. Drivers are available at http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux , but not for newest Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @mook765 thanks for that HUD. Now mirisbowring this is a different situation from that of a VM which as mook765 rightly said uses drivers of the "host" machine. Please when using it natively drivers matter and I believe this might be your issue...

Comment: But can it really depend on the GPU driver? Btw. The driver of AMD homepage is only for Ubuntu 16.04 (I think that I can't use it right?) I've read about a open source driver, but it is said that it is activated natively on Ubuntu... So the GPU driver should be installed :/

Comment: Can I use the "Linux" driver from amd homepage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a Solution to fix this problem.
It seems that the default desktop environment (unity) is not compatible with my system.
I changed to gnome 3 Desktop and for now everything works fine.